# I would like to be able to get this integral evaluation to show up in terms of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

this is very much a beginner question; I was hoping that someone may be able to take a look at this code and tell me why it outputs all of these crazy numbers instead of just the variables specified in the limits. Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: You'll get more assistance if you post the code rather than a picture.  Also, you should note that you've simultaneously cross-posted this question at http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/851608.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You're right, I did cross-post it to the wolfram forum but the way that forum is set up I didn't feel like it would get any responses and it hasn't so far. In the future I will post code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you may have accidental defined some parameters such as Γ and ω0 earlier, because they don't appear in the `Out[64]` line in your image. To clear all definitions, it is sometimes helpful to simply quit the kernel. You can find this option under the "Evaluation" menu.

You also don't need the `Evaluate[]` line. You can simply call `n[ω, ω0, Γ]`.

The following worked for me on a fresh kernel:

```
k[ω_, ω0_, Γ_] := 1/(2 π)* Γ^2/((ω - ω0)^2 + Γ^2)
n[ω_, ω0_, Γ_] := 1 + 2/π Integrate[a k[a, ω0, Γ]/(a^2 - ω^2), {a, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> 0 < ω && 0 < ω0 && 0 < Γ, PrincipalValue -> True]
n[ω, ω0, Γ]
```

This returned the following analytical result:

```
(*1 + (Γ (ω0 (Γ^2 - ω^2 + ω0^2) (π + 2 ArcTan[ω0/Γ]) - Γ (Γ^2 + ω^2 + ω0^2) Log[ω^2/(Γ^2 + ω0^2)]))/(2 π^2 ((Γ^2 + ω^2)^2 + 2 (Γ - ω) (Γ + ω) ω0^2 + ω0^4))*)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I did define those variables earlier and thought creating a new notebook would clear the definitions. I don't have time to check it right now but I certainly will tomorrow. Thanks a ton for your help! Really appreciated.